# make targets and dependencies with repeated wildcard

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile running a data analysis that I am doing for a number of datasets that have a common workflow. I have a number of rules like so...

```
data/a/a.tax : code/a.sh code/a.x
    bash $<

data/b/b.tax : code/b.sh code/b.x
    bash $<

data/c/c.tax : code/c.sh code/c.x
    bash $<
```

I'd like to think that I could do...

```
data/%/%.tax : code/%.sh code/%.x
    bash $<
```

But that doesn't seem to work (`make: *** No rule to make target data/a/a.tax'.  Stop`)

Any suggestions on what would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern rule targets can only contain a single `%`, `.SECONDEXPANSION` can work around this

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
data/%.tax: code/$$(notdir $$*).sh code/$$(notdir $$*).x
    bash $<
```

That said, unless you absolutely need that particular tree structure, it'd be simpler to change the prerequisites to `code/a/a.sh` etc

```
data/%.tax : code/%.sh code/%.x
    bash $<
```